# Question regarding notation involving vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers, and consider the following addition and scalar multiplication operations on $u+v=(u_1+v_1+1,u_2+v_2+1),$ $ku=(ku_1,ku_2)$.

Show that $(0,0)\neq0$.
I'm confused by their notation. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $\mathbf{0}$ they mean the zero vector. The zero vector has to be the additive identity in order for $V$ to be a vector space, in other words, $\mathbf{0}$ has to be a vector such that $\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: Okay. What about (-1,-1)=0?

Comment: Exactly. The example shows that the zero vector does depend on the vector space you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{V}$ be the vector space on V with the above definitions of addition and scalar multiplication. In the statement you are to show, the zeroes on the left side are real numbers making up the components of a vector in $\mathbb{V}$. The zero on the right side is not a real number but a vector in $\mathbb{V}$, namely the zero vector in $\mathbb{V}$. You are to show that the vector $(0,0)$ is not equal to the zero vector in $\mathbb{V}$.